# How to use Google Play Services 7.3.0 on AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin

I've updated my Android SDK and also the PlayServices Library. Nothing seems to work right now.

The import com.google.android.*; does not exists, and I've added the 'compile' lines on the Gradle File.

Have someone experienced this? How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
}
```

That's the Gradle File for a Module.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you post the lines from your build.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Android Studio and want to use the latest Google libraries via Gradle dependency, you will have to update the

You can do this via **Tools** -> **Android** -> **SDK Manager** -> You have to update the stuff under **Extras**

[image: SDK Manager]

---

Also make sure that you are not using the **Offline Mode** of Gradle. You can find this option via (I did this on a Mac)  **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> **Gradle** -> (Global Gradle Settings) **Offline Work**

Make sure this option is **not** checked.

[image: Gradle - Offline Work]

---

Something which was mentioned by @CommonsWare already (and i add it just to sum up this answer) is to sync the project via the Gradle files. You can do this via the toolbar as seen here:

[image: Sync Project via Gradle files]

Or via the menu **Tools** > **Android** > **Sync Project with Gradle Files**

---

If nothing of the above is working for you, it would be really helpful if you can try to build the project via the command line or the terminal with the following command:

```
gradle clean build --debug
```

and then post the output here. It will hopefully show why it can't resolve the library.

Comment: I've everything up to date

Comment: @NemesisDoom i've added another thing you should check

Comment: @NemesisDoom please see the additional solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files and see if that clears up your problem. There's a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=171370) where Android Studio does not always warn you to do this with the yellow banner on the editor.

Comment: Clicked on Sync. I'm going to try with "clean Project"